# Is it possible to create multiple objects from a single declaration of class in Java?

Tags: java

I am not so much expert in java. So When I am practicing about class and I think if there is such opportunity to create multiple objects then it would be great
Is it possible?
or Ecah time I have to declare new object like

```
  Student s2 = new Sudent();
  Student s1 = new Student();

  s1.setInfo("Sujon", 24, 40000, "Software Engineer");
  s2.setInfo("Alam", 25, 35000, "designer");
  s3.setInfo("Fahim", 23, 20000, "Software Engineer");
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

You know "set info" is conceptually exactly what a constructor does, right?

```
Student s1 = new Student("Sujon", 24, 40000, "Software Engineer");
Student s2 = new Student("Alam", 25, 35000, "designer");
Student s3 = new Student("Fahim", 23, 20000, "Software Engineer");
```

[Providing Constructors for Your Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

Comment: Thank a lot. yeah got it now

Answer (score 0):

You can declare multiple variables on the same line. However, it is generally a good idea to declare no more than three variables on the same line. Each variable will then require it's own instantiation, which could either be to three different objects of the same type or to the same object. Here is an example:

```
Student s1, s2, s3;

// Each variable is instantiated to the same object
s1 = new Student ();
s2 = s1;
s3 = s1;

// Each variable is instantiated to a new object
s1 = new Student ();
s2 = new Student ();
s3 = new Student ();

// Now you can make calls to the objects
s1.setInfo("Sujon", 24, 40000, "Software Engineer");
s2.setInfo("Alam", 25, 35000, "designer");
s3.setInfo("Fahim", 23, 20000, "Software");
```

For your particular example, though, you might want to check out how to use constructors, as Michael pointed out in his answer. I think it's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah Thanks a lot 
I got it :)